# How exactly do address lines work in QuickBooks?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, street-address

Right now I'm only trying to read addresses and display them.  Ignoring IPP right now, just inside QB, I'm not understanding the algorithm that manages the address lines.

Further, when accessing the customer address object via IPP, there are more differences, adding to my confusion. I'll call the three areas I'm looking at the freeform block, field block and IPP object.  Here's an example where I typed the text into the field block and made the text match the field name:
[image]
The freeform block and IPP object took the City, State and Zip values and combined them into line 3.  The IPP object has the Note value in Line 4.  And the Country value ends up in the City field in IPP and field block.

Here's an example where I simply typed "line 1 ... line 5" in the freeform block:
[image]
Lines 1 - 4 look ok in the field block after the conversion, and put "line 5" into the City field.  The IPP object is missing Line 4 field and value altogether.

Can someone share with us how this works?  I'm trying to read these addresses and display them in my app in a consistent way.

Comment: Notes for me and anyone else trying to figure this out.  Look at the bottom of the page:  http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0400_Data_Synchronization  _synchronizing addresses with lines 4 and 5 will cause any data in those lines to be lost_

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Quickbooks. But I think you're looking for "[address standardization](http://smartystreets.com/what-is/address-standardization)" since you aren't sure in what format the address will come from Quickbooks.

Addresses are tricky (trust me, I work at SmartyStreets, where we have to be smart ... about streets) but there are services -- free and paid -- which will standardize addresses and put them into a consistent "componentized" format.

Take a look at [LiveAddress API](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api/demo) for starters... or you could use the batch/list service if you export your data into a file. Either way, it's free to use for a certain number of addresses.

(Tip: You can submit addresses for standardization and verification in two fields: "Street" and "Last Line" and still get good results -- so if you're not exactly sure where the city/state are, just put anything that's not the street address in the last line field.)